# Bxslider error in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari, bxslider

So I am designing a website for a client and all seems to be working in other browsers.
However when it comes to Safari, i get this error:

**"TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('.bxslider').bxSlider')"**

The things is Safari will be the client primary focus due to iphones, ipads etc

Can anyone help??

Edit: Sorry really should have put the code instead of link..

```
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   video: true,
       useCSS: false

       });
     });
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you add the relevant part of the code that throws the error, instead of linking that website that looks fishy?